Explicit definition of cartesian multicategories
In the definition of cartesian multicategories of the nlab it says "symmetric multicategory [equiped with contraction and deletion operations ...] which satisfy certain evident axioms".
In the presentation of Shulman, page 116, you see he does something completely different, that is in my opinion way more complex in terms of implementation than having only the three operations on multimorphisms symmetry, weakening and contraction, and specifying axioms for these as the nlab suggests.
Even though Shulman's presentation seems more elegant in some other way and easier to generalize ---as is seen in that particular page--- simplicity of implementation of cartesian multicategories is what I care about right now. For instance I implemented symmetry as permutation of only two objects.
As an example I see that weakening and then contracting should be like doing nothing, permuting two and then contracting those two should be the same as just contracting, etc.
Is this the kind of axiom the nlab is talking about?
I'd like to have an actual list of them, because I have a feeling I'm going to miss a few and also consider some axioms that can be derived from simpler ones.
Thanks in advance!

There’s a reasonable question here, but that said, if you can implement a symmetric multicategory then you should definitely be able to implement Shulman’s presentation of Cartesian multicategories. You’re going from an action by all bijections to an action by all functions; either way you need a way to act by a whole lot of different symmetries.

@KevinCarlson that's a good comment. Indeed I implemented symmetry as permutation of only two objects. Editing.

Cartesian multicategories as multicategories with exchange (a.k.a interchange/symmetry), contraction, and weakening (a.k.a thinning) are introduced as Gentzen multicategories in Definition 10.1 of Lambek's 1989 Multicategories Revisited. I include the definition below for convenience.

Note that an earlier "unbiased" presentation of cartesian multicategories than Shulman's notes is §4.1 of Pisani's 2014 Sequential multicategories.
I'm not sure if there is an explicit proof in the literature that these are equivalent.

That is a great reference, thanks! It seems it assumes implemented full fledged variables and substitution, which I don't know what it means for non-free multicategories; so in that sense it's similar to Shulman's, it's not "combinatorial", or I'm not understanding well what is being meant here; I'm very new to this so this is possible. I had in mind deriving all of the natural deduction rules and see what is necessary for that; I understand that should be enough; for instance the two rules I gave as examples in the question were indeed necessary for the usual rules of equality.

That's true. Perhaps a more concrete presentation is given just before Definition 4 of Staton and Levy's Universal Properties of Impure Programming Languages.

That is definitely the way to go. It also assumes remappings of lists of objects in general, but I just must accept that. This has been very helpful. Cheers!
